# creating a popup that's not tied to a GPS coordinate?

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

Normally popup's in Leaflet are associated with a GPS coordinate. When these popups appear there's an arrow pointing to the GPS coordinate they're associated with. eg.

[image]

What if I wanted to create a popup of that same style that didn't have that arrow and that wasn't associated with a GPS coordinate?

I could do `alert('zzzz')` but that's of a completely different style than the leaflet popup.

I could use [jQuery UI's dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) but again, that's a completely different style.

Like I want the curved corners, the X and the drop shadow that leaflet's other popups have. Mainly for consistency.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it thusly:

```
var popup = L.popup({className: 'infobox'})
    .setLatLng(map.getBounds().getCenter())
    .setContent('<p>Hello world!<br />This is a nice popup.</p>')
    .openOn(map);
```

At the top, I had this CSS:

```
.infobox .leaflet-popup-tip {
    display: none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to hide popup arrow you can use this css:

```
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
    display: none;
}
```

An alternative to `.setLatLng` method is using `.bindPopup` to bind a [popup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup) to a particular leaflet element.